# Exclude directories from a shared folder

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, windows-8, debian, shared-folders

I have an Ubuntu 17 VM on Virtual Box, and my host OS is windows 8.1. I created a shared folder between host and guest OS.

Now, can I execlude a sub-directory from being shared to windows ?

Comment: You mean 17.10, right? Also what does this have to do with Debian (in the tags)?

Comment: You mean a subdirectory of that folder, right? And the virtualised Linux side should decide that you no longer have access to that folder on the host's side. Please ease the wording of your question a bit more.

Comment: Yes, you're understood me right. It may look strange that I need to execlude a sub-directory, but you can find the reason here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036128/windows-issue-with-symlinks-in-vbox-shared-folders